# What is the context behind V1,V2,... columns in the yearly M4 competition dataset?

Tags: tsfresh

I want to forecast time series data on m4 dataset.
As i am exploring m4 yearly dataset i want to see if i understood correctly. Are there 836 timeseries which all are of length 23000? Or have they transposed it so its 23000 time series with lengths 836?
If its the first alternative, what's the context behind the V2,V3 columns? What kind of time series data is it?
[image: m4data]